# React - Cannot access state variable inside map function

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component in a reactjs project. The following code segment works fine. But inside the map function, I am not able to access the state variables. I am getting the below error,

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Even `console.log(this.state.total);` didn't work inside the map function.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        page: 2,
        total: 0,
    };
}
```

```
<Pagination>
{this.state.total > 0 ?
    Array(Math.ceil(this.state.total / 10)).fill(0).map(function (object, i) {
        
        return <Pagination.Item active={false} key={i}>{i + 1}</Pagination.Item>
    }).bind(this) : null}
</Pagination>
```

Comment: can it be that total in your state is still undefined on first render? How does your state look like? Does it have a default value that is a number?

Comment: yes it is set to 0 in the constructor. Later value is set after data is fetched.
 And as it is in the code, it will render if the value is >0

Comment: Can you share the entire component code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the anonymous function in your map to an arrow function like this. Change from this:

```js
map(function () {
  console.log(this.state)
  return ...
})
```

to this:

```js
map(() => {
  console.log(this.state)
  return ...
})
```

Comment: yes this solved my issue, thank you.
I also had to remove " .bind(this)"  from the map function.